# How to automatically reboot after running a command

Tags: updates, reboot

I'm installing updates on a bunch of machines, and I simply want to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

all at once on all machines (after hours of course) and let them run without requiring my input for passwords. However, the above commands don't work, because they all require root permission, and thus require my password each time. Running them all under a single `sudo` concatentated by `&&` doesn't seem to work. Also, if an update has release notes, it'll display any release notes and halt until I exit `less`.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: How about `sudo sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && reboot'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo -s` will prompt you for your password once, then leave you sitting in a root shell that remains until you `exit`.  There you can chain commands like `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && reboot`.

Answer (score 3):

So you don't want your user to have to type in a password to use sudo? You could add a line like this into `/etc/sudoers` or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`

```
username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Or to just allow a few programs like `reboot` and `apt-get`:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Might want to look into some `apt-get` options too like:

```
   -q, --quiet
       Quiet; produces output suitable for logging, omitting progress
       indicators. More q's will produce more quiet up to a maximum of 2.
       You can also use -q=# to set the quiet level, overriding the
       configuration file. Note that quiet level 2 implies -y; you should
       never use -qq without a no-action modifier such as -d, --print-uris
       or -s as APT may decide to do something you did not expect.
       Configuration Item: quiet.

   -y, --yes, --assume-yes
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

   --force-yes
       Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to
       continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially
       harmful. It should not be used except in very special situations.
       Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system! Configuration
       Item: APT::Get::force-yes.
```

Or you could blindly pipe a few newlines or "q"'s into `apt-get`, I used to install one package that would ignore `apt` options like `-y` and wait for a keypress (probably in it's preinst or postinst script). Could try something like:

```
{
sleep 20
echo
echo "q"
} | apt-get upgrade
```

---

And if you're installing the exact same packages in every machine, you don't need to `update` and `upgrade` each one over the internet, you can download all the required `.deb` files once with:

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only [packages]
```

or

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --download-only
```

then install them all from a local / shared folder with

```
sudo dpkg -iR /folder_of_debs
```

Comment: I don't think the line you suggest adding to the sudoers file should be used. The user could easily break his system, as entering a password makes you think about whether it's good to run this command. However, I use this line to remove password entering from shutdown, poweroff and reboot: `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown`, as I often run this commands, and here the password annoys me.

Comment: @the_Seppi That's a good idea, all depends if the user is a regular user, or a "setup only" admin-type user that would want to never want a sudo password. I'll add in a line with just those & apt-get too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The really simplest solution if you're 'root' is

```
apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && reboot
```

And if you're a user on the system, firstly make sure the user is enabled in the sudoers then type:

```
sudo apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && reboot
```